# Angular 4 with MVC Routing refreshes page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, routes, .net-core

I have an angular 4 app with dotnet core 2 and MVC. My home page loads fine, but when I click on a link that should cause client-side routing, I get routed to the page and then it refreshes. After the refresh I am on the right page but I am trying to figure out how to stop the server from refreshing the page (presumably returning a 404) and then the client side showing the site correctly.

Here is my routing config in startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
      routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
      name: "spa-fallback",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

and here is a sample of 2 routing configs in my angular app:
app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ExperienceComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AngularFontAwesomeModule,
      PaymentsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: "home", component: ExperienceComponent },
          { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
          { path: "**", redirectTo: "/home" }
      ]),


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and Payments module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [],
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild([
          { path: "payments", component: LandingComponent }
      ])
  ],
  declarations: [
      LandingComponent
  ]
})
export class PaymentsModule {

}
```

When I click on a link that takes me to `/payments`, I see "loading...." show up for a second and then LandingComponent's HTML is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the request pipeline in Startup.cs under the Configure method:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/home/index";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Basically you're telling ASP.NET that any 404 error should be treated as though the request is staying on /home/index (or wherever your SPA code is - in my case it's usually just in /index.html)